# Compiler grammar and parser are disconnected

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler, grammar

In the process of creating my first toy language, I have created the base grammar for it (which can surely be improved upon, feel free to comment). I am emitting C at the moment.

\begin{align}
    program &\rightarrow (declaration | stmt)^* \\
    declaration &\rightarrow \textbf{let}\ assignment\ |\ \textbf{let}\ identifier \\
    stmt &\rightarrow assignment\ |\ returnStmt\ |\ printStmt \\
    assignment &\rightarrow identifier = expr\\
    returnStmt &\rightarrow \textbf{return}\ \epsilon\ |\ \textbf{return}\ expr\\
    printStmt &\rightarrow \textbf{print}\ \text{STRCONST} \\
    expr &\rightarrow mathExpr\ |\ comparison \\
    comparison &\rightarrow term\ compOp\ term \\
    mathExpr &\rightarrow term\ (addOp\ term)^*\\
    term &\rightarrow factor\ (mulOp\ factor)^*\\
    factor &\rightarrow identifier\ |\ \text{INTCONST} \\
    addOp &\rightarrow (+ | -) \\
    mulOp &\rightarrow (* | /) \\
    compOp &\rightarrow (<|>|<=|>=|==|!=) \\
\end{align}

I am reading from a few sources, trying to wrap my head around how the grammar should be constructed and how to parser should reflect every production the grammar can create. The general idea seems to be (and sounds to me like the most logical course of action), that the parser's functions should follow the grammar, i.e. each non-terminal has it's own function, productions separated by | are made into if statements, productions with Kleene star (*) are made into loops etc.

While implementing the expressions (*expr*) in code however, I have found the most reasonable way to code this requires recursion, therefore deviates from this principle. Whereas until *expr*, I had classes that exactly reflected the grammar for each non-terminal, for example *stmt* is represented by:

```
internal class Assignment : Statement {
    public Identifier ident { get; set; }
    public Expression expr { get; set; }
}

internal class ReturnStatement : Statement {
    public Expression expr { get; set; }
}

internal class PrintStatement : Statement {
    public StrConst strConst { get; set; }
}
```

For *comparison*, *mathExpr* and *term* I have created the `BinaryExpression` class which seems the most logical thing to do:

```
internal class BinaryExpression : Expression {
    public Expression left { get; set; }
    public Expression right { get; set; }
    public string op {get; set;}
}
```

The parsing code is therefore not reflecting of the grammar. What worries me is that, even though this works, it could be hard to extend if I ever need to complicate the grammar further.
My main question: I am not sure if the recursive code shows that the grammar could be rewritten in a different way to reflect it, if the code could be rewritten to reflect the existing grammar without too much spaghetti, or if this is just fine as it is.

Parsing code for the expressions below (please tell me if I should post more code for context):

```
Expression parseExpression() {
    int storePos = pos;
    BinaryExpression comparison = parseComparison();
    if (comparison != null) {
        return comparison;
    }
    // Restore position of token being read since comparison failed.
    pos = storePos;
    Expression mathExpr = parseMathExpression();
    if (mathExpr != null) {
        return mathExpr;
    }
    else {
        logError("expression");
    }

    return null;
}

BinaryExpression parseComparison() {
    Expression left = parseTerm();
    if (left != null) {
        if (match(comparisonOperators)) {
            string op = currentToken().lexeme;
            consume();
            Expression right = parseTerm();
            if (right != null) {
                return new BinaryExpression() { left = left, right = right, op = op };
            }
            else {
                logError("term");
                return null;
            }
        }
        else {
            // could be math expression, so do not log any error here
            return null;
        }
    }
    else {
        logError("term");
    }
    return null;
}


Expression parseMathExpression() {
    Expression left = parseTerm();
    if (left != null) {
        if (match(addOperators)) {
            BinaryExpression expr = new BinaryExpression() { left = left, op = currentToken().lexeme };
            consume(); // operator
            expr.right = parseMathExpression();
            return expr;
        }
    }
    else {
        logError("term");
    }
    return left;
}

Expression parseTerm() {
    Expression left = parseFactor();
    if (left != null) {
        if (match(factorOperators)) {
            BinaryExpression expr = new BinaryExpression() { left = left, op = currentToken().lexeme };
            consume(); //operator
            expr.right = parseTerm();
            return expr;
        }
    }
    else {
        logError("factor");
    }
    return left;
}

Expression parseFactor() {
    if (match(TokenType.IntegralLiteral)) {
        if (int.TryParse(currentToken().lexeme, out int result)) {
            consume();
            return new Factor() { intConst = new IntConst() { value = result } };
        }
        else {
            logError("integer");
        }
    }
    else if (match(TokenType.Identifier)) {
        var fac = new Factor() { ident = new Identifier() { name = currentToken().lexeme } };
        consume();
        return fac;
    }
    else {
        logError("identifier or literal");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Bearing in mind that the [tag:c#] tag [was removed in revision 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/291083/revisions#rev-body-d69aaf4d-b444-455f-8b5b-e8e1f906dcec) based on prior comments, what language is the compiler written in? I see [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-8.0) is utilized which appears to be provided by the [tag:.NET] Framework so perhaps it is [tag:c#] or a similar language

Comment: Please include a tag for the language you wrote this in. Language tags are not optional.

Comment: It is indeed c#. I initially had the tag but someone asked why it was there and it made sense to me that this question could be language agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

The first answer already contains a few points that I do not want to repeat.

Your grammar is not recursive, but it should be. Why? Because without it you quickly end up in a dead end. E.g., you can express `a*b + c`, but not `(a+b) * c` because factors cannot contain `mathExpr`.

A recursive grammar requires recursive calls in the parser. This reflects the principle *"the parser should reflect every production of the grammar"* and does not deviate from it.

Also, you split `expr` into `mathExpr` and `comparison`; however, those should be in a hierarchy reflecting the operator precedence instead of existing in parallel. Exactly like `mathExpr` is not `term | factor`.

Whether an expression is of type Integer or Boolean should not be a matter of the grammar but of semantics. E.g., is `a == s` allowed? If `a` and `b` are of the same type then yes, but if `a` is `int` and `s` is `string`, then probably not. Many programmers think that if-statements require a comparison and therefore, we often see statements like `If b = True Then`. No, it does not. It requires an expression of Boolean type or an expression implicitly convertible to Boolean. This can also be a variable or a method call as in `If b Then`.

```
expr -> simpleExpr (compOp simpleExpr)?

simpleExpr -> term (addOp term)*

term -> factor (mulOp factor)*

factor -> IDENTIFIER | LITERAL | "(" expr ")"
```

In `factor` I changed two things (besides making `identifier` a terminal symbol):

1. I replaced `INTCONST` with `LITERAL`. A constant can also designate an identifier declared as `const int N = 10;` whereas a literal is something like `7`, `true` or `"hello"`. You are missing Boolean literals. E.g., you cannot express `let b = true`. Now, a literal could be an integer or Boolean literal.
2. I added the term `"(" expr ")"`. This is where recursion comes into play. This makes the grammar immensely powerful as it allows expressions of arbitrary complexity to be written.

Answer (score 3):

You are writing a recursive descent parser.  Not unreasonable for something simple.

The * is handled like this:

```
Expression parseTerm() {
    Expression left = parseFactor();
    if (left != null) {
        while (match(factorOperators)) {
            BinaryExpression expr = new BinaryExpression() { left = left, op = currentToken().lexeme };
            consume(); //operator
            expr.right = parseFactor();
            left = expr;
        }
    }
    else {
        logError("factor");
    }
    return left;
}
```

There are a few other issues:

1. IDENTIFIER is a terminal
2. you haven't allowed for `let a = x > y + 1`.  This could be deliberate or an oversight.
3. Your error handling is excessive.  parseTerm() does not need to re-report the error it received from parseFactor.
4. And your error handling may be insufficient.  You should consider what error handling to do in the second call to parseFactor.  (You could, for instance, return expr immediately.)  You might also consider having a ParseError object that can be returned instead of null (which would mean you don't need to do anything in the previous case).
5. You will get recursion when you introduce parentheses, but that will match the grammar.

P.S.  Plan for lots and lots of tests.  Consider these:

```
let = 3
let a = 3
let a b = 3
let a b c = 3
```

Two of these lines are valid in your grammar.